# Wi-Fi vs. Wireless Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

While wireless and Wi-Fi do not mean the same (one could reasonably consider wireless as a hypernym of Wi-Fi), they are often used as synonyms. This poses a certain problem for our emerging taxonomy.

Either we edit posts tagged with either with prejudice and make sure the tag [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) is only used for 802.11 related questions or we create a specific [802.11](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/802.11) tag and synonymize [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) into [wireless](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless).

I'd prefer the second option for two reasons. We would not need to edit every post where someone uses WiFi as synonym for anything wireless and falling back on a hypernym never makes the tagging incorrect. Secondly, a specific 802.11 tag will only be used by people who actually thought about the technology and want to focus on that aspect.

Thoughts?

Comment: Wireless could refer to "Without wires" which means that it could refer to practically any non wired transfer of information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WiFi is basically a technology for Wireless LAN based 802.11 standards so it is a subset of wireless.

> Either we edit posts tagged with either with prejudice and make sure
>   the tag wifi is only used for 802.11 related questions

If the user tags a question with [wireless](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) which is basically [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) specific then I suppose it's fine there is no need to do any extra work, if we want to tag it specifically we can edit it to include [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi). I presume **`not many`** users know of **`802.11`** or **`802.11x`** specifications,so [802.11](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/802.11) posts will be less, here we can **`synomize`** [802.11](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/802.11), [wi-fi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi) to [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi).

> or we create a specific 802.11 tag and synonymize wifi into wireless

Synomizing [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) into [wireless](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) is **`not considered`** apt in my opinion as making so, one **`cannot specifially`** look for `wifi` related questions, instead they get all wireless related posts which contains all other wireless technologies.

Comment: I agree with this, you can't synonymise [wifi] and [wireless] when Wi-Fi **isn't** a synonym - there **are** other wireless protocols and the questions are different!